# Set Default Value in List Spring Boot

Tags: arrays, spring, list, api, post

i want to set a default value like this

```
public Map<String, String> postUsers(@RequestBody Penggunaan penggunaan) {
penggunaan.setDeskripsi("Penggunaan Baru");
PenggunaanRepository.save(penggunaan);
return;
}
```

its work when its not List<> type

how can i set default value in List<> type so the code is like this

```
 public Map<String, String> postUsers(@RequestBody List<Penggunaan>) {
 penggunaan.setDeskripsi("Penggunaan Baru");
 PenggunaanRepository.saveAll(penggunaan);
 return;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have autowired the bean for PenggunaanRepository you can use something like the following:

```
public Map < String, String > postUsers(@RequestBody List < Penggunaan > listOfPenggunaan) {
    listOfPenggunaan.forEach(penggunaan -> penggunaan.setDeskripsi("Penggunaan Baru"));
    return penggunaanRepository.saveAll(listOfPenggunaan);
}
```

Note: As **saveAll** method accepts only **Iterable** object so you cannot pass a single object there.

Answer (score 0):

I think in first method you have mentioned, it takes multiple API calls to perform the task of setting default values. It seems that in second approach you want to set those default values in a single go.
So in order to do that the following must do the work :-

```
 public Map < String, String > postUsers(@RequestBody List < Penggunaan > list) {
     for (Penggunaan penggunaan: list) {
         penggunaan.setDeskripsi("Penggunaan Baru");
     }

     PenggunaanRepository.saveAll(penggunaan);
     return;
 }
```

In this approach we have looped the whole list of objects, setting default value in each of them.